# How to only make one pass of tf.data.dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tfrecord dataset. I want to make inference on the dataset thus I only want to use the dataset once. But if I keep running the iterator, it will throw out of range error in the end.

Comment: can you provide a bit more of context, e.g., provide the code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way to deal with this is to catch the `OutOfRangeError`:

```
...  # set up model, data etc.
next_batch_op = iter.get_next()

try:
    while True:
        batch = sess.run(next_batch_op)
        ...  # do something with batch, e.g. inference
except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    ... # finalize the program
```

This will run through the dataset once, an once the error is thrown you can do something else.